# method to return first not null object without using much if else

Tags: typescript

Typescript I have two objects . Employee1 and Employee2

I need a method which return the non null of this.

Return Employee1  if its not null
Or 
Return Employee2 if its not null
Or 
Return nothing

What is the typescript way of achieving this?I can achieve it using plain if else ; but don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just use logical OR operator, like:

```
return Employee1 || Employee2 || undefined;
```